Create jenkins job that can take name, svn url as input and create jobs based on existing base job
Create jenkins job that can take name, svn url as input and create jobs based on existing base job.
I have build and deploy job. we have to create multiple build and deploy jobs for each applications.
I'm thinking to create single job that creates build and deploy job based on existing jobs.

At a high level, if you want to clone jobs, you can go to Jenkins -> New Item, and here you can specify a job that can be used to copy a new job. If you want  to do this in bulk, you should head into the Jenkins host machine, go to the Jenkins home folder, and look for a folder called jobs. In it, you will have a list of all the jobs that currently exist in your Jenkins with the name of the subfolders correlating to the name of the jobs. You could duplicate these folders as many times as you want, then change the folder name & the config.xml file inside each folder to match your new jobs.
